# Not able to get the specific location of the bookmark in a page using PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBOX 2.0.2 jar to add more than one PDF  in a existing heading bookmarked PDF file. And for the same i am splitting it and merging other PDF.

```
Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
                    splitter.setStartPage(1);
                    splitter.setEndPage(noOfPagesInHeadingBkmrkedPDF);
```

Before Split and merge , i am keeping all the bookmark in HashMap with key as pageNumber and value as bookmark name. And after merge i am setting back the bookmark w.r.t. My query is - how to get the specific co-ordinate (location) of bookmark on the page so that the after merge i should be able to set it back to that particular location of the page.

Code snippet for creating the HashMap before Split :

```
public void getAllBookmarks(PDOutlineNode bookmarksInOriginalFile, String emptyString, Map<Integer, String> bookmarkMap) throws IOException {
PDOutlineItem current = null;
if (null != bookmarksInOriginalFile)
    current = bookmarksInOriginalFile.getFirstChild();
while (current != null) {
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    PDPageDestination pd = null;
    if (current.getDestination() instanceof PDPageDestination) {
        pd = (PDPageDestination) current.getDestination();
        pageNumber = (pd.retrievePageNumber() + 1);  // Do we have any method available to get the location on the specific page ??      
    }
    if (current.getAction() instanceof PDActionGoTo) {
        PDActionGoTo gta = (PDActionGoTo) current.getAction();
        if (gta.getDestination() instanceof PDPageDestination) {
            pd = (PDPageDestination) gta.getDestination();               
            pageNumber = (pd.retrievePageNumber() + 1);
        }
    }
    String bookmarkName = emptyString + current.getTitle();
    if(null!=bookmarkName && !EMPTY_STRING.equalsIgnoreCase(bookmarkName)){               
          bookmarkMap.put(pageNumber-1,bookmarkName);
    }

    getAllBookmarks(current, emptyString,bookmarkMap);
    current = current.getNextSibling();
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you...

Comment: IIRC the trick is to look at the PDPageDestination object. It contains more, depending on the type. Btw PDFBox is at 2.0.17.

Comment: Thank you @TilmanHausherr. The actual location is there in PDPageXYZDestination object (Subclass of PDPageDestination object).

Comment: Then call `getLeft()` and `getTop()`.

Answer (score 1):

As i am able to solve my solution using @TilmanHausherr Suggestion. I am answering my question. I changed the below piece of code :

```
public void getAllBookmarks(PDOutlineNode bookmarksInOriginalFile, String emptyString, Map<Integer,BookmarkMetaDataBO> bookmarkMap) throws IOException {
            PDOutlineItem current = null;
            if (null != bookmarksInOriginalFile)
                current = bookmarksInOriginalFile.getFirstChild();
            while (current != null) {
                Integer pageNumber = 0;
                PDPageDestination pd = null;
                PDPageXYZDestination pdx =  null;
              // These value will give the specific location
                 **int left = 0;
                 int top = 0;**
                if (current.getDestination() instanceof PDPageXYZDestination) {
                    pdx = (PDPageXYZDestination) current.getDestination();
                    pageNumber = (pdx.retrievePageNumber() + 1); 
                    **left = pdx.getLeft();
                    top = pdx.getTop();**
                }
                if (current.getAction() instanceof PDActionGoTo) {
                    PDActionGoTo gta = (PDActionGoTo) current.getAction();
                    if (gta.getDestination() instanceof PDPageDestination) {
                        pd = (PDPageDestination) gta.getDestination();               
                        pageNumber = (pd.retrievePageNumber() + 1);
                    }
                }
                String bookmarkName = emptyString + current.getTitle();
                if(null!=bookmarkName && !EMPTY_STRING.equalsIgnoreCase(bookmarkName)){
                      BookmarkMetaDataBO bkmrkBo =  new BookmarkMetaDataBO();
                      **bkmrkBo.setTop(left);
                      bkmrkBo.setLeft(top);**
                      bookmarkMap.put(pageNumber-1,bkmrkBo);
                }

                getAllBookmarks(current, emptyString,bookmarkMap);
                current = current.getNextSibling();
                }
            }
```

Thank you...

Comment: You may have to add the destination handling also to the segment with "PDActionGoto". (You can have a destination directly or as part of a GoToAction) And never forget that there are other type of page destinations, so your code may only work for selected PDFs and fail for others.

Comment: Yes  i agree with you !!